# selenium webdriver xpath InvalidSelectorError

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am new to selenium and I really have hard times here with dynamic buttons. I am writing selenium webdriver js scripts

I searched on stackoverflow and found few pages with similar errors posted but none of them solved my problems

I want to use this xpath

```
/dom[@domain='localhost:3000']//div[#'search-results']//button[@innertext='Add Contact']
```

and here is my code

```
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/dom[@domain='localhost:3000']//div[#'search-results']//button[@innertext='Add Contact']"))))
```

and get this error

```
InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpa
th expression /dom[@domain='localhost:3000']//div[#'search-results']//button[@in
nertext='Add Contact'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/dom[@domai
n='localhost:3000']//div[#'search-results']//button[@innertext='Add Contact']' i
s not a valid XPath expression.
```

and here is the html

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" data-email-id="user3@netas.com.tr" data-user-id="user3@test1.netas.com.tr" data-name="user3 test">Add Contact</button>
```

Can you help me identify my problem ?

Comment: Is this button of yours contained inside a div having id - `search-results` ?

Answer (score 1):

`#search-results` can be used in CSS selectors for `id` attribute with value `'search-results'`. In XPath you should use `@id='search-results'`

As @JeffC pointed out `[@innertext='Add Contact']` predicate should be replaced with `[.='Add Contact']`

Comment: `button[@innertext='Add Contact']` isn't valid either... it should be `button[.='Add Contact']`. You might add that to your answer also.

Comment: Yep, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The `xpath` you used needs some modifications. You may skip the top level tags like **`dom`** and their `attributes` like **`domain`** and still construct an unique `cssSelector` or `xpath`. More over `#` is used while constructing `cssSelector`. Having said that, I would like to avoid including the text part **`Add Contact`** in our `xpath` as well:

```
/dom[@domain='localhost:3000']//div[#'search-results']//button[@innertext='Add Contact']
```

Looking at the `HTML` you shared we can easily construct a unique `cssSelector` or `xpath` to identify the element as follows using only the `class` attribute as follows:

- **`cssSelector`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-success.btn-sm.pull-right"));
  ```
- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right']"));
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Actually taking xPath directly from chrome solved my problem. Before I took it via a third-party test tool.

Comment: There is no answer, I actually wrote thanks cos no need answer.